# Check confidence level on the entities and intent for chatbots in rasa

Tags: chatbot, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

as I am a beginner to building chatbots, I would like to know how to check the confidence levels for each intent and entity when building a chatbot in rasa. I am using spacy as a Language Processing Pipeline . Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You can check confidence after training, by running a nlu server
`https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.9.2/http/`
OR using python code
`https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.9.2/python/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rasa NLU has an [evaluation feature](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/evaluation/) which lets you evaluate the trained data on a test set. This can then give you a confusion matrix of the results. You can also use this [HTTP endpoint](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/http/#post-evaluate) of Rasa NLU if you want to have full access to the evaluation data.